# hive on tez is not supporting hdfs federation

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, tez

hive version is apache `hive-2.1.0`
tez version is apache `tez-0.8.4`
i set `tez.lib.uris=viewfs://nsX/nameservice/hive/lib/tez-0.8.4-zdh7.1.1-SNAPSHOT-minimal.tar.gz`

when i run a tez job on hive ,it always appears the problem

```
  2017-03-23T15:26:24,255 INFO  client.TezClientUtils (:()) - Using   tez.lib.uris value from configuration: viewfs://nsX/nameservice/hive/lib/tez-0.8.4-zdh7.1.1-SNAPSHOT-minimal.tar.gz
  2017-03-23T15:26:24,255 INFO  client.TezClientUtils (:()) - Using tez.lib.uris.classpath value from configuration: $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,/opt/ZDH/parcels/lib/hadoop/*,/opt/ZDH/parcels/lib/hadoop/lib/*,/opt/ZDH/parcels/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*,/opt/ZDH/parcels/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*,/opt/ZDH/parcels/lib/hadoop-yarn/*,/opt/ZDH/parcels/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*,/opt/ZDH/parcels/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*,/opt/ZDH/parcels/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*,/opt/ZDH/parcels/lib/tez/*,/opt/ZDH/parcels/lib/tez/lib/*
  2017-03-23T15:26:24,260 ERROR exec.Task (:()) - Failed to execute tez graph.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /hive
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.viewfs.InodeTree.resolve(InodeTree.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.viewfs.ViewFileSystem.getFileStatus(ViewFileSystem.java:377)
    at org.apache.tez.client.TezClientUtils.checkAncestorPermissionsForAllUsers(TezClientUtils.java:1031)
    at org.apache.tez.client.TezClientUtils.addLocalResources(TezClientUtils.java:275)
    at org.apache.tez.client.TezClientUtils.setupTezJarsLocalResources(TezClientUtils.java:183)
    at org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.getTezJarResources(TezClient.java:1057)
    at org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.start(TezClient.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.startSessionAndContainers(TezSessionState.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.openInternal(TezSessionState.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionPoolManager$TezSessionPoolSession.openInternal(TezSessionPoolManager.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask.updateSession(TezTask.java:277)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask.execute(TezTask.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1092)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1080)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: You should add the command you used to elicit the output above.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, it is something like tez engine is unable to find the file hive.

Alternatively, you can do one thing, login to hive shell and here set the execution engine to tez, then run the queries inside hive shell they will, in turn, run on tez engine.

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
```

You can refer to [this link](https://acadgild.com/blog/integrating-apache-tez-with-hadoop/) for more information on integrating Tez with Hadoop.

Comment: i have set this.hive on tez on non federation is ok.

Comment: The problem appears on hdfs federation.I found the federation path "viewfs://nsX/nameservice/hive/lib/tez-0.8.4.tar.gz"  will be convert to "hdfs://nameservice/hive/lib/tez-0.8.4.tar.gz"  ,which leads to the path is not correct

Comment: Then you can try setting this property in hive-env.sh file